# Change text inbetween tags - shell script

Tags: python, regex, bash, sed, awk

I have a jsp file that looks like this:

```
<font color="#121212">
<br>
Text 1 
<br>
Text 2
<br>
</font>
```

Does anyone know a quick sed/awk command I could invoke in my shell script to replace "Text 1" and "Text 2" with predefined variables? Text1/2 are just placeholders for this question, the space inbetween those `<br>` tags could be filled with anything.

Update: Changing tags to allow suggestions in python as well.

Comment: If neither `Text 1` nor `Text 2` appears anywhere else, what's wrong with plain `sed -e "s/Text 1/$VAR1/" -e "s/Text 1/$VAR2/"` (provided the variables do not contain `/`)?

Comment: The problem is that I have to assume the content of Text 1 and Text 2 are unknown.

Comment: Than switch to a more powerful tool like Perl.

Comment: So, what are the 'fixed points' in the input? The `<font>` and `</font>` tags with exactly 3 `<br>` tags in between?  Is the colour part of the `<font>` tag fixed too?  If you're not going to use a full XML (HTML) parser, you'll still probably be better off with Perl (or Python, or ...) than trying to use `sed` or `awk`.

Comment: So everything is fixed apart from the Text1 and Text2. All of the other tags will not change. Unfortunately I am restricted in that I must use sed/awk within my shell script.

Comment: Can `Text 1` and `Text 2` be replaced with multi-line text also?

Comment: They won't really need to be. They will both be filled with 1-2 word strings.

Comment: Updated tags, if someone can propose a solution in python I can integrate this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this awk command:

```
awk '/<font /{intag=1}
     /<\/font>/{intag=0 ;br=0}
     intag==1 && /<br>/{br++}
     {print}
     br==1{print "Foo"; getline}
     br==2{print "Bar"; getline}' file
```

This command will replace line just after 1st `<br>` with `Foo` and line just after 2nd `<br>` with `Bar`.

Comment: Thanks for your response, unfortunately this still doesn't work for me because I won't know what text 1 and text 2 actually are, just where in the tags they are located.

Comment: So you want to replace line just after 1st `<br>` and line just after 2nd `<br>`?

Comment: Yes, these tags will not change. However, the tag before text is the fifth instance of a br tag within the file.

Comment: This seems to be very close however it is affecting other tags such as `</center>` by replacing them with Foo.

Comment: Can you pls provide some input sample that is not working and I will try & fix this script.

Comment: I have included a sample in [this](http://pastebin.com/9Hb11ZQv) pastebin link.

Comment: Thanks I will edit my answer in few minutes.

Comment: I have tested my awk command with your provided input and it worked without any issues. Check this demo: http://ideone.com/4yhm47 and see that `</center>` isn't getting affected at all.

Comment: I've added the full source which is throwing the problem as it still isn't quite there. http://pastebin.com/QUdaKDRL

Comment: Yes I saw that and apparently unpredective nature of HTML is like that. This answer will still work if `<font ` and `</font>` lines as well as all `<br>` lines are on separate lines.

Comment: Might it be possible to have a variable that would contain everything I need - `myString="<font color="#121212"><br>$firstArg<br>$secondArg<br></font>` and then use sed or awk to completely replace everything from `<font color="#121212">...</font>` with the variable previously defined?

Comment: Yes I think it should be possible though will require much more code, unfortunately I have some project work to do at present.

Comment: Well you have been a big help so thank you! :)

Comment: You're most welcome, glad to be of any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you have some separator you can use between your blocks of replacement text, e.g. newline:

```
$ awk -v text="foo
bar" '
    BEGIN {
        split(text,t,/\n/)
    }
    /<br>/ {
        if (++c in t) {
            print $0 ORS t[c]
            f = 1
        }
        else {
            f = 0
        }
    }
    !f
' file
<font color="#121212">
<br>
foo
<br>
bar
<br>
</font>
```

Otherwise:

```
$ awk -v text1="foo" -v text2="bar" '
    BEGIN {
        t[++n]=text1
        t[++n]=text2
    }
    /<br>/ {
        if (++c in t) {
            print $0 ORS t[c]
            f = 1
        }
        else {
            f = 0
        }
    }
    !f
' file
<font color="#121212">
<br>
foo
<br>
bar
<br>
</font>
```

Note that you could just add as many blocks of replacement text as you like in the `-v/BEGIN` sections if you had more text between `<br>`s you needed to replace in future and the rest of the code wouldn't change - it just replaces as many blocks as are populated in the array `t`.

I see a couple of answers posted using getline. Make sure you read and fully understand all the getline caveats described at http://awk.info/?tip/getline if you're considering using it. IMHO this problem is not a good candidate for a solution using getline.

Answer (score 0):

sed cannot handle multiline input. It reads lines one by one.

So here is a trick, but it needs a separator that you know will never exist in "Text 1" or "Text 2" (i used µ)

```
cat file | tr '\n' 'µ' | sed -e 's/<br>µ[^µ]*µ<br>µ[^µ]*µ<br>/<br>µYOUR TEXT 1µ<br>µYOUR TEXT 2µ<br>/g' | tr 'µ' '\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would still suggest using another language with an XML parser like Ruby. But this is one way to do it with a shell and awk.

```
#!/bin/sh

FILE=temp.txt
TEXT1="Some things that may include characters not possible with sed."
TEXT2="Some things that may include characters not possible with sed."

awk -v text1="$TEXT1" -v text2="$TEXT2" -- '
    {
        print
        if (/^[[:blank:]]*<font .*>[[:blank:]]*$/) {
            while (getline) {
                print
                if (/^[[:blank:]]*<br>[[:blank:]]*$/) {
                    print text1
                    while (getline) {
                        if (/^[[:blank:]]*<br>[[:blank:]]*$/) {
                            print
                            print text2
                            while (getline) {
                                if (/^[[:blank:]]*(<br>|<\/font>)[[:blank:]]*$/) {
                                    print
                                    while (getline) {
                                        print
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
' < "$FILE"
```

You can remove all those instances of [[:blank:]]* if you want to be more strict.

Comment: Updating tags to allow python solutions as well - I will be able to integrate those.